# Cannot locate namei.c or super.c, etc in linux

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, kernel

Studying linux filesystem, trying to copy over an existing fs and modify it and mount it back to linux, And eventually to create a simple one.

The problem here is that I cannot find all the source files for filesystem.

As google says, they should be at /linux/fs/ext2/, but the only file I am seeing there is a Makefile. I have searched the whole Filesystem disk, nothing comes up.

The systems I have tried are 3 Ubuntu, 1 redhat, all of which have kernel 2.6

Thanks!

Comment: Did you install the packages for the kernel source and headers? Or go to http://kernel.org/ and learn how to compile the kernel (using `make-kpkg` on Ubuntu). You also need to configure your kernel if you compile one...

Comment: And it won't be in an absolute path starting with `/linux` but perhaps with `/usr/src/linux*`

Comment: Thank you Basile. I didn't know that. Will let you know what I get later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download source code of kernel from "kernel.org" , then extract it wit "tar xfz"
then you can find requested "c" program under "fs"

Answer (score 0):

Unless performance is at an absolute premium, it would be better to write a user mode filesystem module, check out [fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/).

Filesystem development is *hard*. For some look at what goes on there, perhaps look at the articles by Valerie Aurora on [LWN](http://lwn.net): UnionFS [part I](http://lwn.net/Articles/325369/), [part II](http://lwn.net/Articles/326818/). She has written a few others there, all worth a read. Perhaps also check up on BTRFS, starting [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/342892/). Note that BTRFS has been in intensive development for more than 5 years, and is still far from being considered stable enough for more than personal experimental use...